# Adobe Air mobile vector graphics looks bad

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air

I have a very simple AS3 app that draws few circles using drawing api and displays an embedded plain SVG file (which is also circle of a smaller radius). The graphics looks good on the emulator (when I change different skins in the FlashBuilder) but looks pretty bad on the actual devices. I tried two HTC Thunderbolt and Asus ePad. I don't scale anything, even if I would I think that will be problem for bitmap but not vector based graphics. Anyone knows if that how it is? Or am I missing something?

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

public class bootest extends Sprite
{

    [Embed(source="circle.svg")]
    private var BackUp:Class;

    public function bootest()
    {
        super();

        // support autoOrients
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        var front:Sprite = new Sprite();
        front.graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff,  1);
        front.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 70);
        front.graphics.endFill();

        front.graphics.beginFill(0xffff00,  1);
        front.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 60);
        front.graphics.endFill();

        front.x = 150;
        front.y = 150;  
        addChild(front);

        var svg:Sprite = new BackUp();
        svg.x = front.x;
        svg.y = front.y + front.height + 25;
        addChild(svg);
    }
}
}
```

[image: emulator vs device]

Left side emulator Vs Right side screenshot from the device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a ballpark guess, but it might be worth a try. AIR mobile stage quality defaults to medium, try using high, or best.

Quick warning about mobile and vectors, they can make mobile apps run slow pretty quick, when possible its best to use bitmaps instead.

Comment: Thanks Tyler! You were right! I wish I'd ask this question earlier )) I hear your advice on vectors, I plan to use minimum graphics. I figured re-sizing bitmaps for each platform and then swapping them at run time to much effort if the graphics is not complex and kept to the minimum....